# Best practice for suEXEC on complex sites?

Tags: php, apache, lighttpd

What is best practice for using suEXEC on complex sites?

We've got a site running under a single vhost, and we want to be able to run different PHP web apps eg /forum /wiki /crm as their own UIDs, to help isolate any potential security threats.

I've used [apache2 + mod_fastcgi + mod_suexec](http://blog.chty.org/post/2007/10/28/Apache2-mod_fastcgi-suexec-on-debian-etch) to split multiple sites to unique UIDs by vhost before. However, mod_suexec's SuexecUserGroup directive only works inside a <VirtualHost> block, and is not valid in a more specific <Directory> or <Location>

Is changing to [lighttpd + suexec](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/SuEXEC) the only way to achieve this level of isolation without resorting to using a rewrite/proxy hack?

Answer (score 2):

Run each app under a separate UID as a separate service under PHP-FPM, and then configure Apache or lighttpd to route to /forum /wiki /crm etc to those different services.

Comment: This. (mod_)suExec still has applicable use-cases but they are *very* niche.